# Excel Macro pattern matching filter

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Can anyone help me write this as a VB/excel macro.

I would like to select the following from one data sheet and write to another data sheet.

Select any rows where in column `T` the field contains the string `SYDNEY-NEWC` or contains the string `F3` but does not contain `F3` in the last 10 characters or where in column `J` the field contains the string `SYDNEY-NEWC` or contains the string `M4 MTWY` or contains the string `F3` but does not contain the string `F3` in the last 10 characters.

Comment: I'm assuming you're writing from a SQL background... do you actually want to 'select' the rows or do you want to do something else with them (chart the data, move to another sheet etc.) ? Just selecting them is often inefficient in VBA.

Comment: Hi I would like to select the data from one data sheet and write it to another data sheet.

Comment: Great, thanks. Can you also just confirm the 'split' in your logic? I'm having trouble distinguishing which of your logical tests are for column T or column J. Perhaps you can split the tests onto several lines in your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a start. It's rough and ready, missing a lot of error checking and the LEN function will fall over if the cell contains less than 10 characters. But this will move across rows that match your pattern:

```
Sub MigrateData2()

Dim intRowCount As Integer
Dim intTargetRowCount As Integer
Dim intColumnCount As Integer

Dim CheckString1 As String
Dim CheckString2 As String

intTargetRowCount = 1

    For intRowCount = 1 To Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

        CheckString1 = Cells(intRowCount, 20) ' contents of column T
        CheckString2 = Cells(intRowCount, 10) ' contents of column J

        If CheckString1 = "SYDNEY-NEWC" Or InStr(CheckString1, "F3") _
          Or InStr(Len(CheckString1) - 10, CheckString1, "F3") > 0 _
          Or CheckString2 = "SYDNEY-NEWC" Or InStr(CheckString2, "M4 MTWY") _
          Or InStr(CheckString2, "F3") _
          Or InStr(Len(CheckString2) - 10, CheckString2, "F3") > 0 Then

            For intColumnCount = 2 To 20 ' change this last number to however many columns you have

              Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Cells(intTargetRowCount, intColumnCount - 1).Value = _
              Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Cells(intRowCount, intColumnCount).Value

            Next intColumnCount

            intTargetRowCount = intTargetRowCount + 1

        End If

    Next intRowCount

End Sub
```

ASSUMPTIONS:

- Your source data is on Sheet1 and starts in cell A1
- Your target sheet is Sheet2 and you want to start writing the data from cell A1

Comment: Hi Gary thank you so much. I will test this out and see how it goes. Alessandra

Comment: Hi Gary Using your very helpful code as a strong base I came up with some code which I was going to post but I only have 491 characters left.